# Is there a way to debug Tomcat Java application from Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I am relatively new to Java but need to do some changes to Java code. I prefer using Visual Studio Code for this. The Java code builds to .WAR file using Maven and is deployed to Tomcat.

Is there any way to debug this app directly from Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Now it is possible debug java: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/09/28/java-debug

Comment: But how to make it work with Tomcat?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434930/how-to-hot-reload-tomcat-server-in-vscode

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code has a lot of tools to do this in marketplace.

For Tomcat you can use this:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adashen.vscode-tomcat

You can do all this things:

- Add Tomcat Server from Tomcat Install Path
- Start/Restart Tomcat Server from VSCode
- Run war package on Tomcat Server
- Debug war package on Tomcat Server
- Run exploded war on Tomcat Server
- Debug exploded war on Tomcat Server
- Open server homepage in browser to check all deployed war packages
- View all deployed war packages in Tomcat Explorer
- Open war package homepage in browser
- Stop Tomcat Server
- Rename Tomcat Server
- Customize JVM Options when starting Tomcat Server
- Reveal deployed war packages in file explorer
- Delete deployed war package

You need the debugger posted by **Mert Mertce** tho.

Comment: It seems that the linked extension is no longer maintained. I also tried Just Start Server, which seems equally "dead" in term of support. I haven't found any extension working consistently at the moment, even if the proposed one works at first glance. It looks like dependency changes break it, which is something pretty usual in a big project.

Comment: I found the Community Server Connectors extension, looking great so far