# How to hot reload Tomcat server in VSCode

Tags: java, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I'm migrating from Eclipse IDE (+ VSCode for coding Java servlets and HTML/CSS/JS webpages, respectively) to only Visual Studio Code for its lightweight.

---

I have several Java extensions installed for VSCode:

- [Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java)
- [Tomcat for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adashen.vscode-tomcat)
- [Debugger for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug)

---

Eclipse has a series of settings for hot reloading:

```
- Automatically publish when resources change
- Refresh using native hooks or polling
```

while VSCode doesn't seem to have any for me.

---

A few things I've try to reload my Java and web code:

- Restart Tomcat server
- Delete and re-adding Tomcat server
- Delete and regenerate `.war` package (not sure if this does anything, it can run well without a `.war` package)

Comment: And the recent feature addition https://github.com/adashen/vscode-tomcat/issues/198 would not help?

Comment: @VonC Nope, it doesn't seem to.

Comment: In Eclipse, only Tomcat is started, and the editor uses vscode.

Answer (score 14):

Good news...

It works automatically now. With Tomcat for Java Extension (And the rest of the Java Extension Pack):
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adashen.vscode-tomcat

Just make sure your settings are like this (search for "java.autobuild" to get those two in the first results):
[image]

Very important is, that you wont see any logs in the console on the HCR (Hot Code Replacement) like it happens in Eclipse ... but you in fact will see the replaced code behavior. Just debug over the piece of code you changed, and you will see it in fact changed in the running server.

**UPDATE:** I've found it works better with the 'manual'(default) setting. Just clicking once in the lightning icon. (Testing in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) 
[I say it works better because if I added lines to a Class' code with the 'auto' setting it will not add that code ... only if I change code in the existing lines. But with the manual setting I just save the file, and then click the lightning icon wait ~3 seconds myself and debug over the new code ... and everything goes well!! 
[image]

... This solves my coding needs(lightweight Editor/IDE with Hot-Code-Replacement in Tomcat)]

Enjoy !

Comment: Hello, does this work for JSP files? I successfully edited java files while debugging but when i'm editing JSP files the changes are not reflected on server.

Comment: It doesnt work on the JPS (or xhtml for JSF) files ... because in the running app those are taken from the deployed war and not from the sources you are working on... and the extension only recompiles and replaces Java classes.

Comment: Thanks, I hope there will be support for it soon.

Comment: Should we specify anything in the Tomcat Servers workspace setting ? Say a path as in `/home/stephane/programs/apache-tomcat`

Comment: I believe it doesn't need it, if you are able to get your tomcat running from vscode with your application, this instructions should work.

Answer (score 0):

This article may be helpful, I migrate from other IDE to Vscode.
According to the article, if you install [Debugger for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug), it enabled Hot code replacement(HCR) and then :

> You can start a debugging session and change a Java file in your development environment, and the debugger will replace the code in the JVM running your code.

[Hot code replacement for java comes to visual studio code](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/hot-code-replacement-for-java-comes-to-visual-studio-code/)

Comment: The 1st link is dead. The 2nd link does not answer the question.

Comment: @GinoMempin, Thanks for your notice.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, I edit this answer, Thanks for your good advice.

Answer (score -1):

Install “Tomcat for java” extension in VScode.

Configure the Path of Tomcat in the above extension.

Now you should be able to run tomcat in usual build -> deploy mode. Now install DCEVM, By using “java -jar installer-light.jar”. (Select “Install DCEVM as altjvm”)

Place HotSwap Agent Jar in directory of your choice.

Now In VScode right-click the Tomcat server you have created. (The one from Step 3 ) And select “Customise JVM Options”.

In the file opened, Place “-XXaltjvm=dcevm
-javaagent:/[your_directory]/hotswap-agent-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar” Now Right-click the tomcat server in VScode and select “Debug WAR package”, And select the WAR file.

If everything goes well, The WAR will be start in TOMCAT in debug mode with text “HOTSWAP AGENT” in the log.

Now your every save to your file will trigger Hot Reloading.

https://medium.com/@manoj_makkuboy/hot-reload-java-8-tomcat-server-in-vscode-ba6233d632e?

Comment: Just in case it works automatically now:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57212212/6254435